# word vba date overflow

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I am creating a macro to automate generating invoices. One thing it will do is assign today's date to a formfield in the invoice and calculate the due date by adding days (inserted by the user in a formfield as an integer) to today's date.

I am getting a very basic error on the macro where the following code runs into "error 6: overflow":

```
dim invDate as Date, dueDate as Date
dim days as Integer
dim invDateFF as Formfield, dueDateFF as Formfield, daysFF as Formfield

set invDateFF = Activedocument.Formfields("Date")
set dueDateFF = Activedocument.Formfields("DueDate")
set daysFF = Activedocument.Formfields("Days")

invDate = Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy")
days = daysFF.Result
dueDate = DateAdd("d", days, invDate)
invDateFF.Result = invDate
```

Both variables (invDate and dueDate) are overflowing...

The formfields are text formfields and they are of a date type. Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: The code works for me with Word2013.  You could use Date instead of Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: I'm on Word 2016 for Mac. Could it have something to do with the computer's language settings? i.e. computer is in Spanish but code is running in English; maybe the formats of dates are different...? What do you mean with "you could use Date instead? thx

Comment: What's the value of daysFF.Result ? Use debug.print daysFF.Result if you don't know now.

Comment: OK... If I run the code one step at a time it overflows, if I run the program it works. Can anyone make any sense out of this?

Comment: Wow, now it's even more weird. The code runs but when I add 14 days to the invoice date it adds 14 years! Even though I have the "d" parameter in the dated function...! I debug.print and the value for days shows as " 14" instead of "14". Why the space? Is that affecting? Thx

Comment: As an observation, I do see this error, but I only see it  when I single-step through the code in VBE. If I wrap the code in a Sub and set it a the Exit macro for the "Days" FORMFIELD, it executes OK. (Incidentally, to *see* the result, I have to do something else, e.g. change the last line so it says invDateFF.Result = dueDate. But that's another story).

Comment: I can't understand, the code is not working in single-step mode OR wrapped in a sub :( Thanks to all for the comments anyway

Comment: When I said "only when I single step", I really meant to say "when I execute the code standalone", i.e. *not* as the on exit macro from a form. But surely the code must be inside a sub/function *somewhere*?

Comment: You are right @bibadia it works when I run the sub "on exit" from a form field. However, if for argument sake I set the variable days to 14, it adds 14 years instead of 14 days. When I Debug.Print(days) it shows " 14" with a blank space in from. The form field is numeric and the variable days is an integer. Even if I do CInt(days) just in case, I still get " 14"... I don't know if this affects the outcome; otherwise, I don't know why it would add years instead of days if the function has the arguments DateAdd( "d", days, invDate)

Comment: I now remember that various problems were introduced in this area in 2015/2015, at least partly because of a change in the way MAC OS X stores default regional date format info. I thought it had all been fixed, but another look at Mac Word 2011 date handling on a system set to dd/MM/yyyy format suggests there are still problems. I'll have a look around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted this as an Answer because the Comments mechanism is too awkward. It certainly isn't an answer to *all* the problems you have encountered, but maybe you can use it as a basis for further discussion.

```
invDate = Format(Now, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

The problem is that the result of "Format" is a string, but invDate has Date type. So you are relying on Word to coerce a date in string format into a Date value, which is not a good idea in the general case. Further, I would guess that the main reason you are doing it is to get rid of the time part of the result of the "Now" function. If so, you can use the Date property of VBA.DateTime instead, e.g.

```
invDate = Date
```

or

```
invDate = VBA.Date
```

Then the following statements should do the right thing:

```
days = daysFF.Result
dueDate = DateAdd("d", days, invDate)
```

But now what you probably want is to plug the result back into your form, which would need

```
dueDateFF.Result = format(dueDate,"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

and/or you can use the properties of the FormField to set the format of the date to the one you want to see (and to be accepted - Word has some flexibility in that area).

Personally I would try to focus on getting the code to do what I wanted - the problem you describe with the "days" variable value is certainly a bit weird, but getting to the bottom of that problem may not be required in order to make progress on the form.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it sure helps with the overflow problem. However, I still don't understand why the DateAdd function adds years instead of days when given "d" as an argument... Do you know? thx

Comment: Did making the changes I suggested make any difference to that behaviour?

Comment: @DNunez On Stack Overflow there should be only one "question" in a Question. If bibadia's Answer has fixed the "big" problem (overflow) - that's also the subject of this Question - then mark it as "the" Answer by clicking the checkbox next to it. Then process all the information you have and post a new Question on the other problem. **NOTE** and please remember to tag MAC questions using the Mac tags, as I did for this post :-)

Comment: Good point @Cindy Meister - apologies, I'm not too geared up on the stack overflow system and need to get familiarized...